# Saving UIViewController in appDelegate

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am using Xcode 4.3 and need to know the parent view controller of the current view.

I am also using storyboard.

`self.parentViewController` always returns `nil`.

I saw different answers to save the parent view controller in `AppDelegate` class as a property. E.g., To create a variable: `UIViewController parentViewController` in AppDelegate and in the code write:

```
appDelegate.parentViewController = self;
```

I am afraid that it will consume memory - as this is a heavy object.

What is the best approach to know `aretnViewController` when using story board?

Comment: If the parent view controller is nil the property is empty. What exactly to you mean with parent view controller?

Comment: To create a variable: UIViewController parentViewController in AppDelegate and in the code write: appDelegate.parentViewController = self;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not an object is "heavy" does not matter as long as you store only a reference to it (in your case in the application delegate). Creating a second object would make a difference, but the line

```
appDelegate.parentViewController = self;
```

does not do that, it merely stores a reference to the object.

I know that this does not answer your direct question, but I think you should go ahead with the "store a reference in the app delegate" approach.

Comment: However, I saw that if I write = self, everytime that I enter a different UIViewController - the self changes to the current view controller!

Comment: @Odelya How does your app work? Is there some sort of navigation involved where the controller object is deallocated each time you leave a screen, and recreated when you re-enter the screen? If this is the case, then you should maybe cut the "heavy" part from the controller class and create a new class from that - let's name it `HeavyStuff`. You could then instantiate `HeavyStuff` exactly once in the app delegate, and provide a reference to the instance via `appDelegate.heavyStuff`.

Comment: I am using storyboard. The navigation is doen with segue. I understood that segue actually creates it each time

Comment: @Odelya Well, then you could try the approach I outlined. Of course you need to be aware of the tradeoff involved: Since the `HeavyStuff` object is now no longer deallocated, your app will have a constantly higher memory usage.